# JQuery Active Refresh Not Working After Server-Side Redirect

Tags: jquery, playframework

I have a page which is refreshing actively every 5 second. But when i click a button from the page which is redirect to itself at server-side and then it's not refreshing. What can i do?

JQuery Code;

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="${_response_encoding}">


// Reload the whole messages panel
var refresh = function() {

    $('#thread').load('@{room()} #thread', function() {
        $('#thread').trigger('create');
    });


}

var create = function(){
     $('#thread').trigger('create');
}

// Call refresh every 5 seconds
$(document).ready(setInterval(refresh, 5000));


</script>
```

Server-Side Code;

```
public static void served(Long servingID) {
    Serving serv = Serving.findById(servingID);
    serv.isServed = true;
    serv.save();

    index();
}
```

Comment: also i tried with $(window).load(setInterval(refresh, 5000)); but still not working...

Comment: Ömer, are you sure you want to refresh whole page every 5 seconds ? it can be serious `performance killer` IMHO. You should choose between two other solutions: 1) use jQuery.ajax() to fetch Json with `only new` messages data (and iterate the result with JS to format and place them at the panels top), 2) use `WebSockets` to keep connection between client and server and perform similar action like in point 1. but only in case when server sends message to the client that is something new that should be updated.

Comment: Marcus, this project must be completed this night. :) And this page only will work at one machine. So this is not a big problem if i can continue to refreshing page after clicking the button...

Comment: Ha, challenge! ;) So solution no. 1 will be just easier and faster. if you have no time for 'fighting' with json and adding new items to the message panel, you can create new action in your controller, let's call it messagePanel() and then use jQuery.get() to fetch rendered HTML - 'ready to use' list of messages and replace the current `<div id="panel">` content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was in FAQ, we have to re-bind events after load data.
http://docs.jquery.com/FAQ#Using_event_rebinding